# Awk understanding variables

Tags: variables, awk

What does the words (probably variables?) like `NF`, `RF`, `FS` mean in awk? I believe they have some pre-defined meaning and usage.

Please let me know, if there are more such variables that must be known to a beginner?

-Thanks

Comment: 8 powerful `awk` vars: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/

Comment: Are you attempting to learn `awk` without reading one of the hundreds of excellent introductions you can easily find in Google?

Comment: I think [SO] is a place that can address such simple questions for the beginners( like me :) ) that come to learn the programming languages. Do you envisage it as a problem?

Comment: I think the problem is with questions that demonstrate a failure to even skim the manual. The definitions of NF et al. are hardly hidden in the man page.

Comment: @chepner The upvote to comment by me. Hadn't gone through the manual. Should make a habbit of going through it completely first. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are built-in variables, in awk they have special meaning.
There is the [part in GAWK reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Built_002din-Variables) covering this topic.
In particular:

**FS**:

> This is the input field separator (see Field Separators). The value
>   is a single-character string or a multi-character regular expression
>   that matches the separations between fields in an input record. If the
>   value is the null string (""), then each character in the record
>   becomes a separate field. (This behavior is a gawk extension. POSIX
>   awk does not specify the behavior when FS is the null string.
>   Nonetheless, some other versions of awk also treat "" specially.)
>
> The default value is " ", a string consisting of a single space. As a
>   special exception, this value means that any sequence of spaces, TABs,
>   and/or newlines is a single separator. It also causes spaces, TABs,
>   and newlines at the beginning and end of a record to be ignored.

**NF**:

> The number of fields in the current input record. NF is set each
>   time a new record is read, when a new field is created or when $0
>   changes (see Fields).
>
> Unlike most of the variables described in this section, assigning a
>   value to NF has the potential to affect awk's internal workings. In
>   particular, assignments to NF can be used to create or remove fields
>   from the current record. See Changing Fields.